# "ValueError: weights can not be broadcast to values. Mismatch at dim 1." when using custom loss function over sequence model

Tags: python, tensorflow, valueerror, mismatch, loss

I was trying to add a custom layer for custom loss calculation to a sequence tagging network under python3.7.4 and tf2.0.0rc1. The code of the custom layer came from the Internet(I cant find it's originator). And This shows up "ValueError: weights can not be broadcast to values. Mismatch at dim 1. values.shape=[32  1] weights.shape=[ 32 104]." when calling model.fit()

The network takes sequences of words as input(shape [numseqs, maxlen = 104]) and output scores(something like unnormalized probabilities) of each tag for each words(shape [numseqs, maxlen, numtags = 18] using a BiLSTM. The loss layer is appended after the model. It calculates loss for each sequence by basically summing up scores of tags and transitions within (shape [numseqs]).

Code that could be relevant  is as follow:

```
#part of class loss_layer(Layer) 's definition
    def log_norm_step(self, inputs, states):
        states = K.expand_dims(states[0], 2) # (batch_size, numtags, 1)
        trans = K.expand_dims(self.trans, 0) # (1, numtags, numtags)
        output = tf.compat.v1.reduce_logsumexp(states+trans, 1) # (batch_size, numtags)
        return output+inputs, [output+inputs]
    def path_score(self, inputs, labels):
        point_score = K.sum(K.sum(inputs*labels, 2), 1, keepdims=True)
        labels1 = K.expand_dims(labels[:, :-1], 3)
        labels2 = K.expand_dims(labels[:, 1:], 2)
        labels = labels1 * labels2
        trans = K.expand_dims(K.expand_dims(self.trans, 0), 0)
        trans_score = K.sum(K.sum(trans*labels, [2,3]), 1, keepdims=True)
        return point_score+trans_score
    def call(self, inputs): #for loss calculation only
        return inputs
    def loss(self, y_true, y_pred): # ys is of shape(batch_size, maxlen, numtags)
        mask = 1-y_true[:,1:,-1] if self.mask_last_label else None
        y_true,y_pred = y_true[:,:,:self.ntags],y_pred[:,:,:self.ntags]
        init_states = [y_pred[:,0]] # initial state
        log_norm,_,_ = K.rnn(self.log_norm_step, y_pred[:,1:], init_states, mask=mask) 
        log_norm = tf.compat.v1.reduce_logsumexp(log_norm, 1, keepdims=True) # logarithm of nomalization coefficient
        path_score = self.path_score(y_pred, y_true) # y_pred's score
        return log_norm - path_score

#to pass the loss function to model
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=crflayer.loss, metrics=[crflayer.accuracy])
```

The complete error code is as follow:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-796bcb8f3510> in <module>
      1 history = model.fit(Xtr_, ytr_, validation_data=(Xval, yval),
----> 2                     batch_size=batch_size, epochs=3, verbose=1)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    726         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    727         workers=workers,
--> 728         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    729 
    730   def evaluate(self,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    322                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    323                 training_context=training_context,
--> 324                 total_epochs=epochs)
    325             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    326 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    121         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    122       try:
--> 123         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    124       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    125         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     84     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     85     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 86                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     87 
     88   return execution_function

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    455 
    456     tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
--> 457     result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    458     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
    459       self._call_counter.called_without_tracing()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    501       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    502       initializer_map = object_identity.ObjectIdentityDictionary()
--> 503       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializer_map)
    504     finally:
    505       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    406     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    407         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 408             *args, **kwds))
    409 
    410     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1846     if self.input_signature:
   1847       args, kwargs = None, None
-> 1848     graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   1849     return graph_function
   1850 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2148         graph_function = self._function_cache.primary.get(cache_key, None)
   2149         if graph_function is None:
-> 2150           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2151           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2152         return graph_function, args, kwargs

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2039             arg_names=arg_names,
   2040             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2041             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2042         self._function_attributes,
   2043         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    913                                           converted_func)
    914 
--> 915       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    916 
    917       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    356         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    357         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 358         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    359     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    360 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in distributed_function(input_iterator)
     71     strategy = distribution_strategy_context.get_strategy()
     72     outputs = strategy.experimental_run_v2(
---> 73         per_replica_function, args=(model, x, y, sample_weights))
     74     # Out of PerReplica outputs reduce or pick values to return.
     75     all_outputs = dist_utils.unwrap_output_dict(

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in experimental_run_v2(self, fn, args, kwargs)
    758       fn = autograph.tf_convert(fn, ag_ctx.control_status_ctx(),
    759                                 convert_by_default=False)
--> 760       return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    761 
    762   def reduce(self, reduce_op, value, axis):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   1785       kwargs = {}
   1786     with self._container_strategy().scope():
-> 1787       return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
   1788 
   1789   def _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   2130         self._container_strategy(),
   2131         replica_id_in_sync_group=constant_op.constant(0, dtypes.int32)):
-> 2132       return fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2133 
   2134   def _reduce_to(self, reduce_op, value, destinations):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    290   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    291     with ag_ctx.ControlStatusCtx(status=ag_ctx.Status.DISABLED):
--> 292       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    293 
    294   if inspect.isfunction(func) or inspect.ismethod(func):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in train_on_batch(model, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics)
    262       y,
    263       sample_weights=sample_weights,
--> 264       output_loss_metrics=model._output_loss_metrics)
    265 
    266   if reset_metrics:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in train_on_batch(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, output_loss_metrics)
    309           sample_weights=sample_weights,
    310           training=True,
--> 311           output_loss_metrics=output_loss_metrics))
    312   if not isinstance(outs, list):
    313     outs = [outs]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in _process_single_batch(model, inputs, targets, output_loss_metrics, sample_weights, training)
    250               output_loss_metrics=output_loss_metrics,
    251               sample_weights=sample_weights,
--> 252               training=training))
    253       if total_loss is None:
    254         raise ValueError('The model cannot be run '

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in _model_loss(model, inputs, targets, output_loss_metrics, sample_weights, training)
    168               per_sample_losses,
    169               sample_weight=weights,
--> 170               reduction=losses_utils.ReductionV2.NONE)
    171           loss_reduction = loss_fn.reduction
    172 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/losses_utils.py in compute_weighted_loss(losses, sample_weight, reduction, name)
    105     input_dtype = losses.dtype
    106     weighted_losses = tf_losses_utils.scale_losses_by_sample_weight(
--> 107         losses, sample_weight)
    108     # Apply reduction function to the individual weighted losses.
    109     loss = reduce_weighted_loss(weighted_losses, reduction)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/losses/util.py in scale_losses_by_sample_weight(losses, sample_weight)
    146 
    147   # Broadcast weights if possible.
--> 148   sample_weight = weights_broadcast_ops.broadcast_weights(sample_weight, losses)
    149   return math_ops.multiply(losses, sample_weight)
    150 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/weights_broadcast_ops.py in broadcast_weights(weights, values)
    165       return weights
    166 
--> 167     with ops.control_dependencies((assert_broadcastable(weights, values),)):
    168       return math_ops.multiply(
    169           weights, array_ops.ones_like(values), name=scope)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/weights_broadcast_ops.py in assert_broadcastable(weights, values)
    114                 "%s Mismatch at dim %s. values.shape=%s weights.shape=%s." % (
    115                     _ASSERT_BROADCASTABLE_ERROR_PREFIX, i, values_shape_static,
--> 116                     weights_shape_static))
    117         return control_flow_ops.no_op(name="static_dims_check_success")
    118 

ValueError: weights can not be broadcast to values. Mismatch at dim 1. values.shape=[32  1] weights.shape=[ 32 104].
```

Could any one recognize what is wrong? Thanks in advance

================Update0================

I just found a way to somehow bypass this error message but it's not exactly a solution. This may be helpful for locating the problem.

The network is expected to take inputs of shape(numseqs, maxlen), forwards them through layers like embedding and BiLSTM, then output scores(unnormallized probability) of each tags for each word in each sequence with shape(numseqs, maxlen, numtags). A decoding algorithm (like Viterbi) is then applied to retrive the tag sequence of maximal sequence_score for each input word sequence. So the custom loss layer is supposed to calculate one single loss value for each sequence, as "return log_norm - path_score"(shape(None, 1), None is for numseqs) in the code of loss layer above. But this somehow causes the error.

By changing the return logic into:

```
    lossvalue = tf.concat([log_norm - path_score]*maxlen, 1)
    return lossvalue # now lossvalue is of shape(None, maxlen=104)
```

the network was then able to be trained.

According to this "solution" and the error message, seems like tf was trying to apply a weight vector shape(maxlen=104) to the loss value shape(1) over batch(batch_size=32). After manually duplicating the loss value over dim1, the error disappeared. But this feels weird. Is there any way to specify a sequence as a whole, over which a single loss value is bound and backpropagated?

I'm so confused. Is there any "normal" solution that is more convinsing?(rather than manually duplicating the loss value over sequence)